# Probability person will make profit?

Tags: probability

A person goes to 6 equal job interviews, they are all independent. He has a probability of $0.40$ to get a job and earns $200$ euros for every job he gets. The costs he makes for the $6$ interviews is $300$ euros.

What is the probability he will make profit?

What is the probability he will lose money?

**Attempt:** I computed the expected amount of jobs he will receive: $0.40 \cdot 6 = 2.4$. So the expected profit will be $2.4 \cdot 200 - 300 = 180 $ euros. But I'm not sure how to use this information to answer the questions. Any help?

Comment: The person will make a profit if he or she lands 2 or more of the 6 jobs, and lose money if he or she lands 0 or 1 jobs. Then the number of jobs landed is binomial, with $p=0.4$, $n=6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $2^6$ possible outcomes for the job-seeker, for example if we denote  a success with $S$ and a failure with $F$, a subset of the probability space might look like $\{SFFFFF,FSSSSS\}$.

In how many of these outcomes will he make a profit? Precisely when the number of successes is at least 2. Otherwise he will only make either $0$ or $200$.

We calculate the probability he makes a loss. There are ${6\choose 1} = 6$ possibilities for only one success and ${6 \choose 0} = 1$ possibilities for exactly $0$ successes. Hence the probability of a loss is given by:

$${6\choose 1}\cdot\bigg(\frac{4}{10}\bigg)^{1}\cdot{\bigg(\frac{6}{10}\bigg)}^5 + {6\choose 0}\cdot\bigg(\frac{4}{10}\bigg)^{0}\cdot{\bigg(\frac{6}{10}\bigg)}^6 = 0.23328$$

We can easily recover the probability he makes profit as: $$1-0.23328 = 0.76672$$

Answer (score 1):

He will make profit if he gets $2-6$ jobs, for which the probability is:

$$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{6}\binom6n\cdot\left(\frac25\right)^{n}\cdot\left(1-\frac25\right)^{6-n}=76.672\%$$

---

He will lose money if he gets $0-1$ jobs, for which the probability is:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{1}\binom6n\cdot\left(\frac25\right)^{n}\cdot\left(1-\frac25\right)^{6-n}=23.328\%$$

---

Of course, you may as well calculate one, and subtract it from $1$ in order to obtain the other...